# How to switch cherrypy.tools.json_out() off for one method in class?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy service replying with json responses. For this I've implemented the `@cherrypy.tools.json_out()` decorator at the top of my class.

I now have one method in the class that needs to respond with an image.
The method sets the `cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type']`corresponding to the image mime-type. It doesn't work if the tools.json_out() decorator is in my code. Without the decorator it works (but than I need to implement all my other methods differently).

I tried setting the `tools.json_out()` off in the config of CherryPy with a decorator on the method, but that doesn't overrule it.
What is the problem with my approach?

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it... 
Sorry for posting too soon.

I actually added the decorator overruling `@cherrypy.config(**{'tools.json_out.on': False})` in the wrong place first.

It needed to be placed in front off the other decorators of the method (`@myservice.expose` in my code) .
Now it works.

Hope this info will help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Please also mark this as a correct answer, if you can :)